# Actionscript regexp search for number of length 4 in string

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I need to find in a string the first occurrence (if exists) of 4 consecutive numbers.

For example:

```
Hello6326 -> 6326
Tomo3753rrow -> 3753
23Thankyou -> (nothing)
1121 -> 1121
```

I know that I have to use the regexp, I tried different solutions but without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[/\d{4}/g](http://regexr.com?33igd)

Sample:

```
    var str:String = "Hello6326 -> 6326 Tomo3753rrow -> 3753 23Thankyou -> nothing 1121 -> 1121";
    var res:Array = str.match(/\d{4}/g);
    trace(res);
```

Output:

```
6326,6326,3753,3753,1121,1121
```

Comment: dammit.. I forgot the `g` after `/\d{4}/`... what does it do  exactly?

Comment: it means _global_ [matches more than one match](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ea7.html)